# Tons of traffic from EBAY,Inc registered IP's

Tags: apache-2.4

I received what I could only call an overrun of traffic on one URL. I geo located the IP's and they all come from eBay, inc. It caused my application to slow down for 10 minutes. What was eBay doing and how can I prevent this? Is this a bot?

Below are some of the access logs:

```
66.135.202.45 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:44:14 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.74 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:46:20 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.74 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:46:36 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.43 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:46:52 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.73 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:44:10 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.43 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:43:45 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.73 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:43:45 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.45 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:47:21 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.42 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:43:49 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.74 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:46:52 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.43 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:47:33 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.42 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:43:45 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.41 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:47:11 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.74 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:45:04 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.71 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:43:45 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.72 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:43:45 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.71 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:47:22 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.74 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:43:44 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
66.135.202.72 - - [14/Aug/2018:12:47:01 +0000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/20820?timestamp=1528634462 HTTP/1.1" 200 540729 "http://www.ebay.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
```

Comment: The item they watched, is it render as a picture or such ? I would tend to think that URL got inserted into an ebay auction.

Comment: It is a picture; but why would all the requests come from an ebay inc ip address and not a client ip address that viewed the image?

Comment: They probably process the image for the client watching the webpage, like a iframe. As else you could log everyone that watched the item, it's an easy way to find who is behind a handle, as you could even match a buy/buy out with the ip logged.

Comment: Why so many requests through?